# How do I call a Rails generator from within the app itself?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need a little bit of help with some unconventional rails generator usage!

I'm trying to programmatically call the Rails migration generator and create a new db/migrate/1234_something.rb file from within my app.

I don't want to type `rails generate migration add_fields_to_thing name:string`, but that's the effect I want.

How do I call a generator programmatically, and have it actually create a file?

This is my approach so far:

```
filename = ['create_something']
atts = ['name:string', 'body:text']

Rails::Generators.invoke('migration', (filename + atts), behavior: :invoke, destination_root: Rails.root)
```

And this runs successfully, but only returns `[[nil]]`

I know this code runs successfully from within a rails generator, but I don't know how to execute the generator, and have it actually create a file, like it would running under Thor.

Any help would be much appreciated!

I know I could just do `system("rails generate migration #{filename} #{atts.join(' ')}")` but I want to run it in the same process so it's fast!

Thanks

Comment: This sounds very peculiar. What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: write a rails site that creates rails sites for me